# What is the GLSL equivalent of gl_PointCoord for LINES?

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

So, in OpenGLES-2 the fragment shader has access to **gl_PointCoord** to see where the fragment is located on a point primitive.

There is also **gl_FragCoord** to see where a fragment is located on the frame buffer.

However, where is **gl_LineCoord**?
It does not exist, so how can my fragment shader know the location of a fragment on a line primitive?

The reason I want to know this, is that I want to do a dashed line, with the dashes in screen space, not world space.

The only way to do this that I can currently think of is taking a sqrt of fragCoord.x^2 + fragCoord.y^2 but that sounds costly and unnecessary if there only was a gl_LineCoord available.

Answer (score 4):

There is no equivalent to what you want. But really, this isn't difficult. Just pass the value 0 at one end of the line, and 1 at the other. Let the interpolation tell you how far along the line you are. That will give you the equivalent of what you want.

Granted, it's not going to help you that much in drawing dashed lines in screen space, but then `gl_PointCoord` wouldn't help you with that either (since it only goes from [0, 1] just like this value).

But you asked for the line equivalent of `gl_PointCoord`, and I gave you that.

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't gl_PointCoord enable me to do a stipple in screen space just by multiplying with gl_PointSize?

Comment: @Bram: No; `gl_PointSize` is not given to the fragment shader. You can pass it of course, but it isn't given directly. And even then, it only works because you were given the value; `gl_PointCoord` *alone* isn't enough.